# What is default order when there is no explicit defined order?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activerecord

In Rails ActiveRecord when I do something like that `event_instances.order(:created_at)` and not specifying any order which order is default `DESC` or `ASC` ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According the [user manuals for rails](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-order), when you've specified a symbol, sorting is setup to `ASC`, when string, default order, which is set by database up, is specified:

```
User.order(:name)
=> SELECT "users".* FROM "users" ORDER BY "users"."name" ASC

User.order('name')
=> SELECT "users".* FROM "users" ORDER BY name
```

Sort orders in DBs:

For [`Postgres`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/queries-order.html):

> ASC order is the default.

For [`MySQL 5.7`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html):

> The default is ascending order; this can be specified explicitly using the ASC keyword.

For [`SQLite`](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html#orderby):

> If neither ASC or DESC are specified, rows are sorted in ascending (smaller values first) order by default.

So for all the main DBs dafault order is `ASC`

Comment: Never knew this fact.. Nice to know.